# If condition is driving me crazy

Tags: powershell, user-interface, powershell-studio

Please I need help... two identical strings are not returning $True when checking on IF logical statement.

The images illustrates perfectly my frustration. I'm starting with GUIs don't be cruel please.

I've tried checking with label text with variables from textbox.text everything that came to my mind...

blob:https://imgur.com/5fcdabfb-b86e-436d-9c57-ed5f97c48229

```
        Write-Host "$Udrive\$($comboSamaccount.Text)"
        Write-Host "$Homedirectory"
        $Udriveinfo = "$Udrive\$($comboSamaccount.Text)"
        $labeUdriveINFO.Text = $Udriveinfo
        $labeUdriveINFO.Text -eq "$Homedirectory"
        if ("$Udrive\$($comboSamaccount.Text)" -eq "$Homedirectory")
        {
            $Ud = "The U drive is - OK"
        }
        else
        {
            $Ud = "The U drive must be changed to $Udrive\$($comboSamaccount.Text)"
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Your link is not working

Comment: Please try with: [link](blob:imgur.com/4f0ed58c-8fe1-49c5-a513-72c70c3eddd0) including blob:

Comment: Nope, still not working

Comment: :(  https://imgur.com/fJtwAmx This one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of troubleshooting this, I'd do the following:

```
$a = "$Udrive\$($comboSamaccount.Text)"
$b = "$Homedirectory"
for($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++)
{
  if("$($a[$i])" -ne "$($b[$i])"){
    Write-Host 'Mismatch found' -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Host ('[{4:D2}] {0}:{1:X} - {2}:{3:X}' -f $a[$i],(+$a[$i]),$b[$i],(+$b[$i]),$i)
  }
}
```

This will go through the characters in the strings one by one and try to find the ones that aren't the same

Comment: Well, it works for what I want, thank you very much! :) But i would like to know why a simple comparison between two strings doesn't work...

Comment: I found the problem thanks to your code Mathias, thank you!

Comment: I found the problem thanks to your code Mathias, thank you!
The problem was that it had spaces... or something that i couldn't see.
$variable.trim() is going to be my ally from now on :D